# Why iframe events not supported in WebDriverEventListener?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

If we look at [WebDriverEventListenr](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.java), it supports many events but not for iframe.

Is there any reason for not supporting it?

Because I've a requirement for iframe as well and want to understand why it is not supported for iframes.

Comment: What do you mean by "not supporting it"? Are you talking about events that happen inside an iframe that is outside of your driver's current context?